# ElasticSearch in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I started to use ElasticSearch in my test project and cant figure out hot to create search for all fields. For instance we have some words as a search query and i want to find all indexed object in ElasticSearch, using Java API.

My obj have: id, name, adress, etc

I searched for this kind of info and wrote this:

```
Node node = nodeBuilder().node();
Client client = node.client();

RegexpFilterBuilder qFilter = FilterBuilders.regexpFilter("_all", (".*" + query + ".*").replace(" ", ".*"));
        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index)
                .setTypes(type)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                .setPostFilter(qFilter)
                .setFrom(0).setSize(100).setExplain(true)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

 SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();
 System.out.println("Current results: " + results.length);
```

I also tried to use one field:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index) 
        .setTypes(type)
        .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
        .setQuery(termQuery(field, value))
        .setFrom(0).setSize(100).setExplain(true)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

I always get 0 result.

Can you show me, how to do this in right way in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i spent more time on documentation and i found a solution, hope it helps to someone else!
You just need to use QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery, the value is our searching word and other strings are the columns where to search to.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index)
        .setTypes(type)
        .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(value,
                "name", "address1", "city", "postalCode",
                "countryCode", "airportCode", "locationDescription",
                "shortDescription"
        ))
        .setFrom(0).setSize(100).setExplain(true)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```